# Efficient way to delete a value from an unordered_map, when given just the value C++

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-map

I have an abstract class called `Object` and I am using `std::unordered_map<int, Object*> objects` to contain these `Object`s within a class called `DataSet`. Each object has an `id` associated with it.

Normally, when deleting an object from my `unordered_map`, I can just do `iterator = find(id)` and then call `erase` on that iterator.

This is easy and efficient. The problem is, I have to implement a method to delete an entry/pair by value, rather then by the key (which was my `id`). This gives me the following prototype:

`int DataSet::DeleteObject(Object* object)`

What is the most efficient way of accomplishing this though? I'm thinking I can do something like this:

```
if(object){
    for(auto kv : objects) {
        if(kv.second == object) {
            objects.erase(kv);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

But it seems very inefficient. So what would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you sure there is only single object matching with your condition? If you need to remove multiple objects, why there is return after first `erase`?

Comment: More importantly, does it seem *correct*? What if the value exists multiple times? Or not at all? And `erase(kv)` doesn't work. You have to erase by *key*, not by value, i.e. `erase(kv.first)`.

Comment: I don't think there is an efficient way to remove an object from a map with only its value. Specially if the map is unordered.

Comment: @Steephen You are right. Updated it to fix that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't perform the lookup twice; erase via iterator:

```
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); )
{
    if (it->second == needle) { m.erase(it++); }
    else                      { ++it;          }
}
```

This deletes all occurrences of `needle`. If you want to erase at most the first occurrence, a simpler loop will do:

```
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
{
    if (it->second == needle) { m.erase(it); break; }
}
```

If you want to erase *exactly* one element, you need to add a check that you found any needles. This can be achieved with `find_if`, which may also be used as a variation of the previous algorithm:

```
auto it = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(),
                       [&needle](const auto & p) { return p.second == needle; });

if (it != m.end()) { m.erase(it); }
else               { /* no such element! */ }
```

Comment: It's a matter of taste but I prefer using `it = m.erase(it)` instead of `m.erase(it++)`